# Typescript Compiler Not Enforcing Generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

### Question

I have a reducer model with an action that accepts a `payload` expecting a shape of `{ id: string, newValues: Partial<A_or_B> }`. In the code below, the enforcement of type `A_or_B` is not enforced when I declare `newValues` inline; however, if I declare `newValues` ahead of time and assign properties to it, the constraints are enforced. **How can I enforce the constraints on `A_or_B` even when `newValues` is declared inline?**

### Problematic Code

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppDispatchContext } from "../src/AppProvider";
import { ActionTypes, A_or_B } from "./interfaces";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useContext(AppDispatchContext);

  const x: Partial<A_or_B> = {};
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type
  // 'Partial<A> | Partial<B>'.
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Partial<A>'.
  x.color = "red";

  dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.POINT_UPDATED,
    // why can I assign a color to Partial<A>|Partial<B> if 'color'
    // only exists on B?
    payload: { id: "x", newValues: { color: "red" } }
  });
}
```

### CodeSandbox Link

[CodeSandbox Link Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-with-partial-types-ch45i?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: For reference, here's a simpler case https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaZAXwFgAoUSWRFAIU2RLwGcwpQBzSrVoIA9iG7IAbnAA2edAB9krALxtcyAIwAmAMwAadngDkcTgBMYxysgD0t5AHcAFgE9kwTsjDPP2GTIijhDmtNIyAHRwyGo6unYOJARg+CIpPp4A-EA Is that the same issue?

Comment: @Alex Wayne Sort of…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem most people experience with [`union`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types in typescript. Some treat them as if they were intersection types, while a few wish they behaved more like mutually exclusive types.

However, typescript has two different interpretations of union types, depending on your use-case.

#### Properties

When you attempt to **access** the property of a union type, you can only access properties that are *common* amongst all members of the union. Another way to say this is that you only have access to the *intersection* of the properties of the members of the union.

That may be a mouthful, but the typescript docs give a nice [analogy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) to explain this:

> For example, if we had a room of tall people wearing hats, and another
> room of Spanish speakers wearing hats, after combining those rooms,
> the only thing we know about every person is that they must be wearing
> a hat.

So in the case of property access, typescript only allows a subset of properties to be accessible (without any further hints from the user), thus forming an intersection.

#### Membership (aka type inference)

When it comes to type inference, the compiler is quite liberal with what it allows to match a union type. Essentially it says, *if you want to be part of this group, you just have to look like one of the members of this group*. In this case, you don't have to have a property that matches the property of *every* member of the union.

---

Maybe the solution to your problem is to just use intersection type for `x`:

```
const x: Partial<A&B> = {};
x.color = "red"; // works!

...
newValues: x; // also works
```

This solves the problem of both *property access* and *membership*

Answer (score 1):

The constraints actually are being enforced in your payload. You can verify this by adding a property on your payload that doesn't exist on type A or B.

The real issue here is *Type Inference*.

```
  const x: Partial<A_or_B> = {};
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type
  // 'Partial<A> | Partial<B>'.
  // Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Partial<A>'.
  x.color = "red";
```

`x` is assigned a valid union value but Typescript can't tell if it's of type A or B, so `x.color` can't be verified since TS thinks there is a possiblity it can be of type B.

```
payload: { id: "x", newValues: { color: "red" } }
```

`newValues` is explictly set to an object that only contains `color` which means Typescript knows that this must be of type A.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmQZzClAHNkBfAWAChRJZEUAhTZBAewBt2o9DiQZKtRqcIYZDHbs8ABThQwwOJwA8qAHzIAPsnmLlaphoDcNGlPbIAvJnLIHjp85fOA9G+QAVAJ4AHCHwEYj8JRCRQ-GQwAAtgKLgE5AA3FWAAE2QAVxBgdhBkACMsiQQ4EAByUvyYYCgAW2iYuAlgVqj2GGj-FHQeboDkJnNqSwA6Dm4oG2QKqAh0itdlhw9kAGVQJG8eoJCJZvxK6pBahqaWyWlkeOROncG+6aYAGhvq+r9OOFAo2MuAERwAE3I5VO4FMA9IYjSwzLCTHh4OYLCpvXCzACMACYAMwAFiW9jWqBIPxAb1SnAy2Vy+Vh0gmXH6tgB83SIJWrjW6y8AEkADICh6BYLAUJscrgjinOqNWIoKGDAAUHCynEyhV6d2eBCUnE4AEoGVZbAjmbxZuzZsILIzEdNbBVCpwshAllz3J4AHIAeQA6iK9uLSuVJKAVJwfGwanKLhI4bd7kqUPolCp1BogA)